# Set cache header in hapi

Tags: node.js, caching, express, http-headers, hapi.js

How can I set the cache-control header in hapi to 'no-cache', 'no-store', 'must-revalidate'?

In express I am able to do the following:
`res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');`

I currently have the following in hapi but I think it may be incorrect:

```
function(request, reply){
  var response = reply();
  response.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  response.header('Cache-Control', 'no-store');
  response.header('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate'
}
```

Is it possible to do this in hapi?

```
function(request, reply){
  var response = reply();
  response.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
}
```

Comment: How to force caching for some file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. That string (`'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'`) is just the single value of the header, so set it like any header. By calling the `header()` method on the [response object](http://hapijs.com/api#response-object).

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        reply('ok').header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: How do you do this for all routes?

Comment: You could set the header in a route lifecycle extension point. Take a look at `onPreResponse` in the hapi docs

Answer (score 1):

In hapi v17 and v18 you can set the header in this way

```
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  handler: function (request, h) {
    return h.response('ok').header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
  }
});
```

The documentation: https://hapi.dev/tutorials/caching/?lang=en_US